# Help with Validation Rule

Tags: validation

I am trying create a rule that will fire if the field is not blank and the length of the field is 7 or 10 or if the field does not start with 609.  Here is what I have.  The problem I had was the rule was not firing as expected as a result of my logic.

AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Phone__c)),
        OR(
        LEFT(Phone__c, 3) <> "609",
        LEN(Phone__c) <>7,
        LEN(Phone__c) <>10
     )
)

Comment: And...what is going wrong?

Comment: The length will always be either not 7 or not 10, this should fail every record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the logic for the 7 or 10. AS it is currently written if it - 7 then does not = 10 so result is true

try this

```
AND( 
  NOT(
    ISBLANK(Phone__c)
  ), 
  OR( 
    LEFT(Phone__c, 3) <> "609",
    AND(
     LEN(Phone__c) <>7, 
     LEN(Phone__c) <>10 
    ) 
  )
)
```

Now if it =7 or = 10 then result is false, anything else result is true